# How to create a fake progress bar for chatbot in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, progress-bar, chatbot

I am working on chat bot. I want it so that until the user calls out his name, a progress bar will be there that will be running in a rectangular shape that will have inside it "Michael is listening". Something like this

```
=========================
|| Michael is listening ||
=========================
```

I want these lines moving in a clockwise direction but not as equal signs and vertical dashes, I want to use the alive_progress library in python. Here's the documentation on github. https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress

Since it has a variety of progress bars, maybe I can use the random module to generate a random number and have it use it as an index to decide the progress bar shape to use.

The problem I am having is that, how to make the this **fake** progress bar animation in python using alive_progress  ?
And then maybe use the equal and dash signs animation when the chatbot hears his name called out, how to make it look like they are moving ?

Comment: can't you use animated .gif instead of python code?

Comment: Whoa, that's actually really smart

Comment: But will it be obvious that it's a gif ? I want to make it look like text just like in the console

Comment: you can draw text in console, take screenshots and create animated GIF. But first you should write more details in question about tools/modules which you use. If you don't use GUI frameworks then you can't display images. Some GUI may not have function to display animated GIF. etc. It amay need other details to check if it all is possible.